# How to execute a Javascript function from a C# WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax

I'm doing some web automation via C# and a WebBrowser. There's a link which I need to 'click', but since it fires a Javascript function, apparently the code needs to be executed rather than just having the element clicked (i.e. element.InvokeMember("click")). Here's the href for the element, which opens an Ajax form:

```
javascript:__doPostBack("ctl00$cphMain$lnkNameserverUpdate", "")
```

I've tried:

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("javascript:__doPostBack", new object[] { "ctl00$cphMain$lnkNameserverUpdate", "" });
```

and:

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("__doPostBack", new object[] { "ctl00$cphMain$lnkNameserverUpdate", "" });
```

and a few other things. The code gets hit, but the script doesn't get fired. Any ideas would be most appreciated.

Gregg

BTW Here's the full element in case it's useful:

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$lnkNameserverUpdate','')" onmouseout="window.status=''; return true" onmouseover="window.status='Update Nameservers'; return true" id="ctl00_cphMain_lnkNameserverUpdate" onclick="javascript:Layout.ChangeIframeToSrc('DropinLoad_Domain.aspx?controlRequest=ActionNameserversWithIP');return false;">NS51.DOMAINCONTROL.COM<br/>NS52.DOMAINCONTROL.COM<br/></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting.aspx

I've actually used this in the past, and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
HtmlDocument doc = browser.Document;
HtmlElement head = doc.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement s = doc.CreateElement("script");
s.SetAttribute("text","function sayhello() { alert('hello'); }");
head.AppendChild(s);
browser.Document.InvokeScript("sayHello");
```